# How do I make this CSS animation that shows a transition from a trapezoid to a rectangle work properly?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to make a door close shut using CSS animation. I was able to get it working for most of it except for the end when the door is meant to be closed.

I had to choose a trapezoid shape for the door closing part.

However, the closed door is a rectangle.

The doorway is a rectangle too. I made a div called "rectangle" that had the dimensions of 100px height and 60px width for the doorway.

Because I had to superimpose the door onto the doorway, I made the doorway rectangle have a z-index of -30.

The problem comes when I have to morph the trapezoid into a rectangle. Something bizarre happens.

I can't make the door a rectangle with the same dimensions as the doorway (60px width and 100px height) - it ends up looking strange.

This is the CSS:

```
 #rectangle {
    width:60px;
    height:100px;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: -30;
}

    
#animate {
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 10px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: example;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
         left: 78px;
         top: 10px;
     }  
     
     @keyframes example {
  0%   {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 10px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
         left: 78px;
         top: 10px;}
  25%  {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 20px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
         left: 68px;
         top: 10px;}
  50%  {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 30px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
         left: 58px;
         top: 10px;}
  75%  {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 40px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
         left: 48px;
         top: 10px;
        }
  90% {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 50px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
         left: 38px;
         top: 10px;
         }
         
   100% {border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
        border-left: 60px solid lightBlue;
        border-top: 10px solid transparent; 
        width: 0;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
         left: 28px;
         top: 10px;
         }  
} 

.shapes {
     
      text-align: center;
       margin: 0 auto;
       float: left;
     }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div id="rectangle" class="shapes"></div><div id="animate"></div></div>
```

I have tried the below for the closed door:

```
 100% {height: 100px;  
       width: 60px;
       position: relative;
       left: 28px;
       top: 10px;
       background-color: lightBlue;
         }
```

The `left` and `top` are probably wrong values but even if I adjust them to make the door fit the doorway better, the door morphing into a rectangle looks strange during the animation.

[image: door closing 1]

[image: door closing 2]

The two images are the door almost closing. They look OK but when I add the closed door, the animation goes strange.

EDITED: Removed paused state.

Comment: I copy/pasted the code and it just stays open. Is there anything else included? Edit: It was just because play-state: pause. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this for 100%

```
100% {
            border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
            border-left: 60px solid lightBlue;
            border-top: 0px solid transparent;
            width: 0;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works a charm! @Anthony